# Find an example of a set $A$ and functions $f :B\to B$ and $g:B\to B$ such that $f\circ g=id_B$ but $g\circ f\ne id_B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Find an example of a set $A$ and functions $f :B\to B$ and $g:B\to B$ such that $f\circ g=id_B$ but $g\circ f\ne id_B$.

I am not sure what $id_B$ means, so I don't understand how to find a set of functions for this. What is $id_B$ and how do you find functions for it?

I know what it means to find functions such that $f\circ g=f$ and similar to this, but now idea how to do this for $id_B$.

An example for $f\circ g=f$ is
$$
f(x)=x+3; \qquad g(x)=x
$$
then $f\circ g=f(g(x))=f(x)=x+3$.

Is there an easier way to find these than trying random equation?

Comment: Do you mean a set $B$ instead of $A$? Also, $Id_B$ is probably the _identity function_ on $B$, defined by $Id_B(b)=b$ for all $b\in B$ (the function that "does nothing").

Comment: `not sure what idB means` Wherever you got the problem from, should have explained what `idB` means in that context beforehand. Most likely it's the [identity map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) of set $B\,$, but it's never a good idea to even attempt to answer questions which you don't fully understand what they mean to ask.

Comment: "*is there an easier way to find these than trying random equations*"... by spending enough time with mathematics, you eventually see a large number of interesting examples which you store in your toolbox for future use, so to answer your question "from memory" is a much easier way to answer questions like this.  I'd expect you want to use simpler sets, but for a rather exotic example, consider the sequence space $\ell_2$ and the operators $L$ and $R$ where $L(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots) = (a_2,a_3,a_4,\dots)$ and $R(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)=(0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$.  You have $L\circ R=id$ but $R\circ L$ isnt

Comment: Those operators I mention are called [shift operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) and have several interesting properties.  That being said, if you are at the level that you are just trying simple functions on the reals such as $f(x)=x+3$ and $g(x)=x$, then it would be obvious that you didn't come up with the example I just gave, so you should keep looking for one more suited to scenarios you are used to.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm reading $A$ as $B$.)

For any set $X$ the map ${\rm id}_X$ is the *identity map* of $X$, and is defined as
$${\rm id}_X:\quad X\to X,\qquad x\mapsto{\rm id}(x):=x\ .$$
Here is an example of the required kind:

Let $B:={\mathbb N}_{\geq0}=\{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$, and define
$$g:\ B\to B,\quad k\mapsto g(k):=2k;\qquad f:\>B\to B,\quad n\mapsto f(n):=\left\lfloor{n\over2}\right\rfloor\ .$$
Then $f\circ g={\rm id}_B$. On the other hand $g\circ f\ne{\rm id}(B)$ since $g\circ f(1)=0\ne1$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** If $f \circ g = \textsf{id}_B$, then it follows that $f$ is surjective (onto) and $g$ is injective (one-to-one). Thus, try finding a set $B$ and any function that is surjective but not injective (or injective but not surjective). Work out a pseudo-inverse for the other function, and you're done!